# Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask about RDF and SPARQL datasets?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions concerning semantic data?

Specifically, my question is about geographic data concerning an ontology derived from [OpenStreetMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap) in RDF which I will query using SPARQL. I want information about the ontology, and about where I can find documentation for that specific data set.

Comment: I would think the best source for that kind of information would be from the the OpenStreetMap project itself.  What is the specific question?

Comment: I want information about the ontology itself, which I did not find in linkedgeodata.org. Since openstreetmap is not the same project as linkedgeodata that won't work.

Comment: It's a Hail-Mary question anywhere on SE.  Someone from the project would have to stumble into it, and it's off-topic on the largest sites (SO, SU, SF) that have the highest traffic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OpenStreetMap data is Open Data I expect a very focused question might be on-topic on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as their help states:

> Open data, as defined by the Open Definition, is any kind of data that can be freely used, modified, and shared by anyone for any purpose.
>
> If you have a question about …
>
> - where to find any kind of open data
> - specific open data sets
> - software tools related to open data
> - best practices regarding open data
> - licensing and releasing open data
> - open data formats and standards
> - linked data, ontologies and related semantic technologies
> - analysis and visualization of open data

They do have tags for [RDF](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdf) and [SparQL](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sparql) but I also notice that they refer to the more specific sites like [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) for specific / detailed questions. By the looks of it for technical aspects related to the datasets. You might have to split your question into several distinct ones and determine for each one what the best site will be.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to have a Web Data SE? There is a proposal for one just started here [Web Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120833/web-data)

Comment: Web Data proposal was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

A site for [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) is currently in beta.